# Minimum speed for a mantis shrimp punch to create cavitation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, estimation, shock-waves

When a [mantis shrimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis_shrimp) punches it creates [cavitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavitation), because of the speed it creates sudden changes in the water.
I want to know how slow can a mantis shrimp punch and still make cavitation?

Notes:

From what I researched cavitation occurs where there is low pressure/water vapor, the water boils because of the low pressure.
The water pressure where mantis shrimps live is $65.564$ psi, and the water pressure needed to make water boil at $23$-$29$ $^o$C is $0.40$ - $0.58$ psi. That’s the temperature of the water where they live.

I need to calculate what speed must the mantis shrimp punch to change the water pressure from this $65.564$ psi to $0.40$ - $0.58$ psi.

I don’t know how to calculate this, or even where to start.

If you have working out then please show it in full.

Any response is very much appreciated.

Comment: One very crude way to estimate this speed is to use Bernoulli's equation. A number of simplifications go into this, but assume that the speed is constant, the flow is irrotational and inviscid, then you have $p/\rho=-1/2(u^2+v^2)$ for $\rho$ the density of water. Assuming the flow is entirely in the $x$ direction, we have $ p/\rho \approx 65=1/2  u^2$,  so that $u \approx 30 m/s$ or about $67 mph$.

Comment: @Nick P that is faster than it states in the link

Comment: @NickP can you explain further your working out, and what is $P$ is it momentum? whats $u$ is it energy? and what's $v$? I don't know how you got to $30m/s$

Comment: @NickP http://www.softschools.com/formulas/physics/bernoullis_equation_formula/469/ is this what your talking about, i will try to do caculations suning this formula. Let'ssee how it goes.

Comment: @AlifPapp Yes, use $P_i + ½ ρ v_i^2 = P_f + ½ ρ v_f^2$ where $P_{i,f}$ (my $p$) is initial/final pressure and $v_{i,f}$ is initial/final pressure. Make sure to use the right units on everything to get formulas that make sense. The "real" answer, i.e. what happens in nature, is significantly more complicated, as the flow around an object in a real fluid contains vorticity, and will diffuse momentum. So in a lot of ways this is a very crude way of estimating this speed, but a good to perform a back on the envelope computation, if you were say, thinking of designing an experiment to check this.

Comment: @NickP this is what i got, for the formula $Pi+½ρv2i=Pf+½ρv2f$ since $vi$ is 0 because it just begins it's punch, then $452.05kpa + 1/2*997*kg/m0$ = $4kpa + 1/2 997kg/m v2f$ therefore i got 0.95m/s for final v which does not make sense.

Comment: The density of water $\rho$ is around $1000 kg/m^3$. 1 psi is about $7*10^3 N/m^2$ so that $(P_i-P_f)/\rho \approx 4.5*10^2 N/m^2$. Then $v\approx 30 m/s$.

Comment: @NickP I'm sorry i dont understand your working out, can you write it out fully with every litle step included. Because i want to replicate your working out my self but i am unable too.

Comment: Doesn't the shrimp claw create a small shock wave or is it the cavitation bubble that creates the shock wave?

Comment: @honeste_vivere The cavitation buble when implodes creates the shockwave